# How to import a file from a subfolder when you are in another subfolder? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm currently in the 'strategy.py' file and I'm trying to import 'utils.py' and 'BaseStrategy.py' ('utils.py' is a file with some functions in it, 'BaseStrategy.py' contains a class with the name 'BaseStrategy').

Folder structure:

```
program\
  __init__.py
  main.py
  folder1\
    __init__.py
    utils.py
    BaseStrategy.py
  folder2\
    __init__.py
    strategy.py
```

In 'main.py' I'm able to import both files like this:

```py
from folder1.BaseStrategy import BaseStrategy
from folder1 import utils
```

So how can I import 'utils.py' and 'BaseStrategy.py' in 'strategy.py'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: @iqmaker Can you explain it to me by using a folder structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys    
sys.path.insert(0, 'program/folder1')
from folder1 import utils
from folder1 import BaseStrategy
```

You can also change the:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'program/folder1')
```

To:

```
sys.path.append('../')
```

But it will mess up with the import from your parent directory (main.py). However you can overcome that with :

```
import os,sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to put a blank file named `__init__.py` in the  subdirectory. If you want to take a look at the documentation you can do so [here (6.4)](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html).

Answer (score 0):

find:

```
./main/
./main/folder2
./main/folder2/__init__.py
./main/folder1
./main/folder1/base.py
./main/folder1/__init__.py
./main/__init__.py
```

cat ./main/folder1/base.py

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd() + '/..')

import folder2
```